# Another way to test the value of an enum in C++

Tags: c++

In C i can test the value of an enum using if/else statement. For example:

```
enum Sport {Soccer, Basket};


Sport theSport = Basket;

if(theSport == Soccer)
{
   // Do something knowing that it is Soccer
}
else if(theSport == Basket)
{
   // Do something knowing that it is Basket
}
```

Is there another way to do this work with C++?

Comment: this is not "type checking", you are merely testing the value of an enum..

Comment: You can use templates to do *actual* type checking.

Comment: Soccer = 0
Basket = 1, enums are not type checking see @gliderkite 's anwser for types

Comment: Thanks to all, I did not know that was not type checking.

Comment: Well... this is the C way of emulating runtime type checking. You'd label a certain kind of data with an enum, to know its type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, instead of using if-else statement, you can use virtual functions as part of interfaces.

I make you an example:

```
class Sport
{
public:
    virtual void ParseSport() = 0;
};

class Soccer : public Sport
{
public: 
    void ParseSport();
}

class Basket : public Sport
{
public:
    void ParseSport();
}
```

And after use your object in this way:

```
int main ()
{
    Sport *sport_ptr = new Basket();

    // This will invoke the Basket method (based on the object type..)
    sport_ptr->ParseSport();
}
```

This is thanks to the fact that C++ adds object oriented features.

Comment: Two remarks: 1. Use pure virtuals in interface (`= 0`); 2. Do not use dynamic allocation when it is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

You can

1 use template magic at compile time to perform different actions for different and unrelated types;

2 use inheritance and polymorphism at run time to perform different actions on types related by inheritance (as in gliderkite's and rolandXu's answers);

3 use C-style `switch` statements on `enum` (or other integer types).

EDIT: (very simple) example using template:

```
/// class template to be specialised
template<typename> struct __Action;
template<> struct __Action<Soccer> { /// specialisation for Soccer
  static void operator()(const Soccer*);
};
template<> struct __Action<Badminton> { /// specialisation for Badminton
  static void operator()(const Badminton*);
};

/// function template calling class template static member
template<typename Sport> void Action(const Sport*sport)
{
   __Action()(sport);
}
```

Comment: Could you make me an example using template?

Comment: @Nick In the particular case here, run-time polymorphism is usually preferrable (since both `Soccer` and `Badminton` are `Sport`s and hence related), but the above works for *any* types.

Answer (score 2):

you are still testing the value in C, that is enum value, not the type of theSport.
The C++ supports runtime type checking, called [RTTI](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/RTTI)